# Keeping XSD assertions in a separate schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I would like to add assertions to an XSD but keep the assertions in a separate schema file. This is because the XSD is provided by a third party and new versions are frequently released.

Third party XSD (SchoolModule.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1" id="SchoolModule"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="../Includes/Address_Structure.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="School" type="SchoolStructure"/>

    <xs:complexType name="SchoolStructure">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Headteacher" type="xs:String" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="SchoolCharacteristics" type="SchoolCharacteristicsStructure"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="SchoolCharacteristicsStructure">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SchoolName" type="SchoolNameType"/>
            <xs:element name="SchoolType" type="SchoolTypeType"/>
            <xs:element name="NumberOfPlaces" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                        <xs:maxInclusive value="999"/>
                        <xs:totalDigits value="3"/>
                        <xs:fractionDigits value="0"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="IntakeType" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

This is what I've attempted in the separate file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1" id="Assertions"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="SchoolModule.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="assertions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:assert test="/Message/School/SchoolCharacteristics/SchoolType ='Secondary' and /Message/School/Headteacher"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Where I'm trying to make the assertion that the Headteacher element should only be present if SchoolType = Secondary. However, this doesn't seem to be working as even if I'm setting SchoolType in my XML file as something other than Secondary and the Headteacher element is present, my XML file is validated successfully. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Note: I've verified that the XPaths in the assertions are correct and return the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD assertions may only be over the content model of the associated element.  You can't constrain markup globally from `xs:assert`.

You might instead write XSLT that could transform the original XSD to one containing your assertions in the proper locations.  However, you'll have to take care that the original XSD, which you say is frequently changing, remains compatible with your assertions (or adjust your assertions accordingly).